# Points on the sides of hyperbolic triangle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Let D be a triangle in a hyperbolic plane.  Prove that there exist
points
A,B,C on three different sides of D such that diameter of the set
{A,B,C}
is bounded by a constant which is independent from the choice of
D

Comment: Hint: consider the largest possible triangle. How would you choose the points to minimize diameter? How can this help for other triangles?

Comment: @MvG: I understand that the largest triangle is important from the point of view of this question. But how would you choose the three points?

Comment: I suggest you draw an ideal triangle in the Poincaré disk model in a symmetric fashion. Then one obvious choice is picking the points in a symmetric fashion as well. Work out a way to characterize that choice without depending on the model, and calculate the distance between these points.